# Creating Excel File with Open XML and ExtremML- gives “…unreadable content…”

Tags: excel, openxml

Hi all I'm using Open XML and ExtremML to generate an Excel File on the Server and Download it, but when you I try to open it it gives me the error "EXCEL FOUND UNREADABLE  CONTENT. DO YOU WANT TO RECOVER THE CONTENTS OF THIS WORKBOOK?
IF YOU TRUST THE SOURCE OF THIS WORKBOOK, CLICK YES", so checking on the file inside y found it's adding a tag named company, that when i remove it it corrects the error that Excel is giving, It's in VB .NET, this is my code:

```
Protected Sub btnExcel_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnExcel.Click
  Dim iProcess As String = ""
  Dim loOraClientDb As clsOraClientDb = New clsOraClientDb
  Dim vFilename As String = ""
  Try
     Try
        iProcess = "btnExcel_Click 1"
        Dim ExcelSendInfo As DataTable = Session("dtExcel")
        Dim ExcelExportedInfo As DataTable = New DataTable
        Dim PkgOutValues() As String = {}
        Dim ExcelDataSet As DataSet = New DataSet
        Dim vtablename As String = ""
        Dim vtabletoname As String = ""
        Dim WFT As New WebFileTools
        If chkFLayout.Checked Then
           iProcess = "btnExcel_Click 2"
           Dim sDNS As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()
           If Not chkFInfo.Checked Then
              For Each dr In ExcelSendInfo.Rows
                 sDNS.AppendLine(dr(0))
              Next
           End If

           iProcess = "btnExcel_Click 3"
           If Not loOraClientDb.Open(ConnectionStrings("DatabaseSDSTP6301").ConnectionString) Then
              EnableErrorByState(loOraClientDb.Message & ", Process: " & iProcess)
              Exit Sub
           Else
              iProcess = "btnExcel_Click 4"
              Dim vStatus As String
              If ViewState("CurrentWindow") = "Report" Then
                 vStatus = "G.G_STATUSID!=2"
              Else
                 vStatus = "G.G_STATUSID=2"
              End If

              iProcess = "btnExcel_Click 5"
              Dim PkgInParameters(6)() As String
              PkgInParameters(0) = New String() {"VEXPORTEDDNS", "VARCHAR2", "Empty", sDNS.ToString.Replace(Chr(13) & Chr(10), ",")}
              PkgInParameters(1) = New String() {"VSTATUS", "VARCHAR2", "Empty", vStatus}
              PkgInParameters(2) = New String() {"chkFInfo", "VARCHAR2", "Empty", BoolToStr(chkFInfo.Checked)}
              PkgInParameters(3) = New String() {"VSEARCHOPS", "VARCHAR2", "Empty", DDLSearchOps.SelectedValue}
              PkgInParameters(4) = New String() {"VSEARCH", "VARCHAR2", "Empty", txtsearch.Text}
              PkgInParameters(5) = New String() {"VRANGE1", "VARCHAR2", "Empty", txtrange1.Text}
              PkgInParameters(6) = New String() {"VRANGE2", "VARCHAR2", "Empty", txtrange2.Text}
              Dim PkgReturnParameters() As String
              PkgReturnParameters = New String() {"VRETURN", "CURSOR", "Empty"}
              Dim PkgOutParameters(0)() As String
              PkgOutParameters(0) = New String() {"VTOTPROJS", "NUMBER", "Empty"}

              iProcess = "btnExcel_Click 6"
              If Not loOraClientDb.ExecuteProcedureFunction("PKG_GENERALINFO.GENERATEEXCEL", PkgInParameters, _
                                                      PkgOutParameters, PkgReturnParameters, , ExcelExportedInfo, _
                                                      , PkgOutValues) Then
                 EnableErrorByState(loOraClientDb.Message & ", Process: " & iProcess)
                 Exit Sub
              End If
              vtablename = "MAININFO"
              vtabletoname = "MAINTABLE"
           End If
        Else
           iProcess = "btnExcel_Click 7"
           ExcelExportedInfo = ExcelSendInfo
           vtablename = "TIMEREP"
           vtabletoname = "TIMEREPORT"
        End If

        ExcelDataSet.Tables.Add(ExcelExportedInfo)
        ExcelDataSet.Tables(0).TableName = vtablename
        Dim vFileTemplate As String = ""
        Dim RandomNumber As New Random()
        If vtablename = "MAININFO" Then
           vFileTemplate = "FullLayout.xlsx"
           vFilename = "FullLayout" & RandomNumber.Next(1000).ToString & ".xlsx"
        Else
           vFileTemplate = "TimeReport.xlsx"
           vFilename = "TimeReport" & RandomNumber.Next(1000).ToString & ".xlsx"
        End If
        Session("vfilename") = vFilename
        WFT.CopyServerFile("ExcelTemplates\" & vFileTemplate, "ExcelTemplates\" & vFilename, True)
        Using DPSExcelTemplate = ExcelOpenPackage(Server.MapPath(".") & "\ExcelTemplates", vFilename.Replace(".xlsx", ""))
           ExcelWorkBookPopulateDS2Table(DPSExcelTemplate, ExcelDataSet, vtablename, vtabletoname)
        End Using
        Server.ClearError()
        Response.Redirect("DownloadPage.aspx", False)
        iProcess = "btnExcel_Click 28"
     Catch ex As Exception
        EnableErrorByState(ex.Message & ", Process: " & iProcess)
        If File.Exists(Server.MapPath(".") & "\ExcelTemplates\" & vFilename) = True Then
           File.Delete(Server.MapPath(".") & "\ExcelTemplates\" & vFilename)
        End If
     End Try
  Finally
     loOraClientDb.Close()
     ShowCorrespondingWindows()
  End Try
End Sub
```

The page DownloadPage.aspx has this code:

```
Imports WebFileTools
Imports System.IO

Partial Class DownloadPage
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
  Dim vfilename = Session("vfilename").ToString
  Dim nfilename = ""
  If vfilename.IndexOf("FullLayout") <> -1 Then
     nfilename = "FullLayout_" & Today.ToShortDateString
  Else
     nfilename = "TimeReport_" & Today.ToShortDateString
  End If
  Dim WFT As New WebFileTools
  WFT.DownloadServerFile("ExcelTemplates\" & vfilename, MIMEType.Excel2007, nfilename)
End Sub
End Class
```

I can't seem to find the problem has anyone gotten this error or knows how to fix this problem?

I Forgot to add this code thats for generating the Excel file with ExtremMl:

```
Public Shared Function ExcelOpenPackage(ByVal ServerPath As String, _
                                            ByVal ExcelFileName As String) As ExtremeML.Packaging.SpreadsheetDocumentWrapper
        Dim ExcelPackage = SpreadsheetDocumentWrapper.Open(ServerPath & "\" & ExcelFileName & ".xlsx")
        Return ExcelPackage
    End Function
```

And this is to fill the info on the file:

```
Public Shared Sub ExcelWorkBookPopulateDS2Table(ByRef ExcelPackage As ExtremeML.Packaging.SpreadsheetDocumentWrapper, _
                                                    ByRef Data As DataSet, _
                                                    ByVal DataTableName As String, _
                                                    ByVal ExcelTableName As String)
        Dim ExcelTable = ExcelPackage.WorkbookPart.GetTablePart(ExcelTableName).Table
        ExcelTable.Fill(Data, DataTableName)
    End Sub
```

Comment: reviewing my code more, I learned that the problem is when downloading the file, because when I copy my template to a new file then populate the file I can open it with no problem, but once is downloaded to the client that tag gets added I don't know if it's something to do with the mimetype

Comment: well I already checked that my IIS has the MIMEtypes correctly added and they are so I still dont know the reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly why but the problem was with my  Download code previusly it was like this:

```
Public Sub DownloadServerFile(ByVal FileToDownload As String, ByVal MIMETYPE As MIMEType,   Optional ByVal NewNameOfFileToDownload As String = "")
  Dim FileExt As String = ""
  Dim F2DArr As String = Path.GetFileName(FileToDownload)

  Current.Response.ClearContent()
  Current.Response.ClearHeaders()

  Select Case MIMETYPE
     Case WebFileTools.MIMEType.Excel2007
        Current.Response.ContentType = _
                "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
        FileExt = ".xlsx"
     Case WebFileTools.MIMEType.Word2007
        Current.Response.ContentType = _
                "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"
        FileExt = ".docx"
     Case WebFileTools.MIMEType.PowerPoint2007
        Current.Response.ContentType = _
                "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation"
        FileExt = ".pptx"
  End Select

  If NewNameOfFileToDownload.Trim.Length > 0 Then
     Current.Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "inline;attachment;filename=" _
                           & NewNameOfFileToDownload & FileExt)
  Else
     Current.Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "inline;attachment;filename=" & F2DArr)
  End If

  Current.Response.Clear()
  Current.Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath(".") & "\" & FileToDownload)
  Current.Response.Flush()
  If File.Exists(Server.MapPath(".") & "\" & FileToDownload) = True Then
     File.Delete(Server.MapPath(".") & "\" & FileToDownload)
  End If
  Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()
End Sub
```

Now i changed this line Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest() for Current.Response.End() and the file gets downloaded correclty

and now i cant call my download code directly:

```
Server.ClearError()
        WFT.DownloadServerFile("ExcelTemplates\" & vFilename, MIMEType.Excel2007, nfilename)
        iProcess = "btnExcel_Click 28"
     Catch ex As Exception
        EnableErrorByState(ex.Message & ", Process: " & iProcess)
        If File.Exists(Server.MapPath(".") & "\ExcelTemplates\" & vFilename) = True Then
           File.Delete(Server.MapPath(".") & "\ExcelTemplates\" & vFilename)
        End If
     End Try
  Finally
     loOraClientDb.Close()
     ShowCorrespondingWindows()
  End Try
```

It's not suposed to be the correct way of using Response.End, because it always trows an error but I don't now if this is the correct way of using Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest() or that Response.End does something that CompleteRequest is not doing in order for it to get the correct MIME Type